# How to detect armeabi and armeabi-v7a from C code

Tags: android-ndk

I'm building a fat APK that contains separate *.so libs for `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a`. I build using the command line only (i.e. using `ndk-build` and `ant`). Is there a way to detect from my C code whether the `ndk-build`is currently building for `armeabi` or for `armeabi-v7a`? Preferably, I would like to be able to detect this at compile time, but if there is no other choice an architecture detection at runtime would also be sufficient.

E.g. is there something like

```
#ifdef __armeabiv7a__
...
#else
...
#endif
```

to detect the architecture at compile time?

I know that I can pass additional compiler flags in `LOCAL_CFLAGS`in `Android.mk` but these flags are always passed for all architectures so it doesn't help me. Or is there a tag that I could use in `Android.mk` to pass specific flags for `armeabi` or `armeabi-v7a`only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that I can pass additional compiler flags in `LOCAL_CFLAGS` in Android.mk but these flags are always passed for all architectures

There's nothing preventing you from setting a flag only when building for a certain ABI:

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DARMEABI_V7A
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

At least gcc provides quite a bit of predefined macros that one can check, to get info about the current ABI. For this case, you could check either this:

```
#if defined(__ARM_ARCH) && __ARM_ARCH >= 7
```

Or this:

```
#ifdef __ARM_ARCH_7A__
```

By manually setting these in the makefile as suggested by Michael you don't need to keep track of what different ABI macros there are, though, and have less risk of getting into unintended situations if moving to a compiler that doesn't have the same predefined macros (such as the MSVC compiler, although you won't be using that for Android).

Comment: check out ndk sample `android-ndk-r10e\samples\hello-jni\jni\hello-jni.c`, there is detecting of all supported abis